# SQL Server Agent best practices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a new environment where there are multiple SQL servers, and I have many, many, MANY SQL jobs that need to be scheduled.

I'm thinking about setting up a SQL server that does nothing but handle the scheduling of jobs for all of these other servers, and would house a database which would be used for logging.

Would this be considered best practice?  Could I run into any issue with long running jobs?  My concern is that even though I would have Server A kick off a stored proc on Server B, that it may cause a lot of network traffic between the two servers.

Thanks

Comment: What kinds/types of jobs are they?  Do they vary from one SQL server to the next?

Comment: Yes, they vary.  Some are just simple stored procs or SQL calls, while others are rather complex SSIS packages.

Comment: In my environment, I created SQL Jobs that are identical on all of the production servers.  They're all for maintenance purposes (backups, rebuild indexes, update stats, etc).  It's pretty easy for me to administer them through a registered server group.  Can you unify some of the jobs so they perform the same task on each server?  (I have some jobs that are BI-related or app-specific.  I'm not directly responsible for those.  If they fail, I notify a developer and provide help as needed.)

This is a tough call for you.  I'd lean toward de-centralized maintenance.

Comment: These aren't server maintenance jobs, but jobs that are application specific and generated by developers.